# Visual Studio 2013 using old Website name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

So in Visual Studio 2012 I renamed a website in a solution from "oldname" to "newname". I have opened this solution in Visual Studio 2013 and somehow it is using "oldname" for the website instead of "newname". This is not is NOT an ASP.NET website application just an ASP.NET website.

I have searched the content of all files in the solution directory and cannot find "oldname". I am 100% positive that that "oldname" is not in the .sln file and the website does not have a project file of course.

Comment: If you mean a web site "project" (File->New Web Site), then you have found yet another reason to not use them. No project - no name.

Comment: Oh @JohnSaunders we have had this discussion before haven't we lol ;).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config` file. It suspect it should have the old name. Rename the website in the file, close your solution and open it back again.

Comment: Correcta Mundo! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is how I managed to do it with my solution in Visual Studio 2015:

Close your solution > navigate to .sln-folder > .vs (hidden) > config
[image]

Look for error prone names (possible multiples) in the sites section. I removed every `<site></site>` where there were naming conflicts. In my case I had  this for example: [image]

After removing the `<site></site>`-sections from the current applicationhost.config-file I was able to re-add website projects with my new and correct name!

Comment: This worked for VS2022

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread but I tried just modifying the applicationhost.config file and closing the solution but it still didn't take.

If this happens to you just remove the site from your solution and then add an existing one from your local IIS instance and you'll see the renamed version there.

You may want to confirm its location before removing the site.